# To Retrieve data from tables

Tags: sql, database, db2

I have two tables

Table A

```
Cust_ID | Channel_CODE
```

Table B

```
Channel_code | Channel_name
```

I want all the `channel_codes` and `channel_names` which a `cust_id` has not subscribed.

Suppose in table B we have

```
101 | Discovery_channel
```

then I want all other channels except discovery channel for customer id 101.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use JOIN and NOT IN() for this:

```
SELECT t.Cust_ID,s.Channel_code,s.Channel_name
FROM (select distinct cust_id from TableA) t
INNER JOIN TableB s ON(1=1)
WHERE s.Channel_code NOT IN(select f.Channel_code from TableA f
                            WHERE f.Cust_ID = t.Cust_ID)
```

This will give you all the channel_codes that a customer_id is not watching